# Install R in conda environment offline

Tags: r, anaconda, conda

I have access to a headless, air-gapped server, where I have Anaconda installed.

The default `R` on server is located at `/usr/local/bin/R` with version `3.1.2`.

On one of my environments, I wish to install `R`, along with certain packages. I downloaded `R` version `3.5.1` source files from [Anaconda repository](https://anaconda.org/r/r/files) and ran the command

```
conda install Downloads/r-3.5.1-r351_0.tar.bz2
```

which executed successfully

> Downloading and Extracting Packages
>
> ################################################################################################################################### | 100%
>
> Preparing transaction: done
>
> Verifying transaction: done
>
> Executing transaction: done

However, when I check if `R` is installed inside the environment, I still get the previous location and version. How can I access the newly installed `R` ?

Comment: Did you install the dependencies as well? I.e., `r-base >=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0, r-recommended 3.5.1.*` and all their dependencies, etc.  (Click the (i)nfo icon next to the file on Anaconda Cloud to see such info).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in comments section, I installed the dependencies separately (`r-base >=3.5.1,<3.5.2.0a0, r-recommended 3.5.1.*`) and the problem was solved.